# Child outlet goes empty when I refresh the url with id from {{link-to}} in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

I have a weird issue, the child outlet goes empty whenever I will refresh the page with the id. I have a list generated by {{link-to}} helper.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="twod">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                <img src="/img/2DPipeline.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="span3">
                <h4>People with Roles</h4>
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="span2">    
                        <ul>
                            {{#each item in model}}
                <li>{{#link-to 'twoduser' item}}{{item.firstname}} {{/link-to}}</li>
                            {{/each}}

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span">
                            {{outlet}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </script>
```

Here's the twoduser template,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="twoduser">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
              Full Name: {{firstname}}{{lastname}}
              EMail: {{email}}
            </div>
        </div>

        </script>
```

App.js,

```
    App.Router.map(function() {
        this.resource('twod', function() {
            this.resource('twoduser', {
                path : ':user_id'
            });
        });
        this.resource('threed');

    });
App.TwoduserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(params) {
        return App.Twod.findBy(params.user_id);
    }
});

App.Twod.reopenClass({
    findAll : function() {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $.getJSON("http://pioneerdev.us/users/index", function(data) {
                var result = data.users.map(function(row) {
                    return App.Twod.create(row);
                });
                resolve(result);
            }).fail(reject);
        });
    },
    findBy : function(user_id) {
        var user = App.Twod.create();

        $.getJSON("http://ankur.local/users/byId/" + user_id, function(data) {
            user.setProperties(data.user);
        });
        user.set("user_id", user_id);
        return user;
    }
});

App.TwodRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return App.Twod.findAll();
    }
});
```

Selecting each one individually works fine and fills the child outlet, but when I refresh it, it goes blank.

Any ideas what might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two possible problems.

The first is that your URLs are different between `findAll` and `findBy`.  Was that intentional?

The second is that `findAll` returns an Ember promise (`Ember.RSVP.Promise`), but `findBy` does not.

[UPDATE] : Based on the JSBin in the comments : http://jsbin.com/iPUxuJU/1/

The problem here is that the API endpoint is returning an array in the `user` response.  It currently looks like this:

```
{user : [{ ... }] }
```

Ideally it would look like this :

```
{user : {....} }
```

You could change the API endpoint, or you could update your code to pull the first element from that array.  Instead of :

```
user.setProperties(data.user);
```

You could do :

```
user.setProperties(data.user[0]);
```

Here's an altered JSBin : http://jsbin.com/oquBoMA/1#/twod/2

Comment: So, the URLs should be same? I am not an expert,that's why I am asking. Second, Whenever I use Ember.RSVP.Promise, I get this,  Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver' or 'removeArrayObserver'.

Comment: I don't know enough about what you're trying to do to know if the URLs should be the same.  When I go to http://pioneerdev.us/users/index I get a list of users, including one with the `id` of `1`.  When I try to go to http://ankur.local/users/byId/1 I don't get anything since 'ankur.local' is not a resolvable host.  It's really hard to debug these kind of things without a running example.  If you can post a JSBin I'd be happy to take a peek.

Comment: Okay, give me a second &  I will post a JSBin. :)

Comment: OK, I added an [UPDATE] section to my original answer.

Comment: Ah! I see what I was missing on. Thanks a lot for the help! :)